# What is deciding the current of an AC to DC circuit

Tags: voltage-regulator, transformer, dc, rectifier, ac-dc

I'm a beginner, trying to build a power supply based on the sketch below to convert 230V AC to 5V DC. My final aim is to supply precision voltage for Arduino, which I think is 5V 700mA.

Here is the circuit diagram:
[image: Circuit Diagram]

So what are the parameters here to decide the current, or how can I get a sharp 5V 700mA DC output? Also do I need to add any more components here to make it more precise for this purpose?

Also one more request: The Voltage regulator specified is LM7805. Is that OK or are there better options? Kindly advice any serious changes needed on the circuit.
(Reference I'm using here is [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xSr8xesyp-s&index=18&list=PL5Px9-Sf7rEnGandu1OuJfr1tqogRbCsF))

Comment: Me thinks you are missing the point. You need a 5V supply capable of giving you AT LEAST 700mA. Your wording implies you want to generate a 5V Supply with EXACTLY 700mA, which is bogus.

Comment: it's (almost) all in the transformer at those output levels.

Comment: @Trevor OK... So it needs some serious fine tuning with the components to get that sharp output.. isnt it?

Comment: No... other than the fact it's horrendously inefficient as others have mentioned, because it can supply more current than your max requirement, it should work fine for your application with the addition of an appropriate heat-sink.

Answer (score 4):

Let's look at what each part of your circuit does:

[image]

The transformer converts 230 VAC to 12 VAC.  The current available at that 12 V is a function of the transformer.  Look at the transformer datasheet.  It will either have a rated output current directly, or a overall VA rating.  The VA rating is the maximum amps times volts the transformer can handle.  For example, a 15 VA, 12 V transformer can supposedly handle (15 VA)/(12 V) = 1.25 A.

Note that this 12 V is RMS.  The peaks of a sine wave are sqrt(2) higher than the RMS.  12 V RMS therefore means 17 V peaks in this case, ±17 V overall.

The four diodes are arranged in a *full wave rectifier* configuration.  This basically takes the absolute value of the input voltage.  The absolute value of a ±17 V waveform is something that varies from 0 to 17 V.  Effectively, the negative peaks are folded up to become positive peaks.  Your drawing is a reasonable representation of this.

However, the full wave bridge isn't ideal.  There are two non-ideal diodes in series with each portion of the output signal.  Figure each diode drops about 700 mV, so the output will be about 1.4 V less than the ideal 17 V.  Figure the peaks are about 15.6 V coming out of the full wave bridge.

The capacitor is like a tank that holds voltage.  It is filled by what comes out of the full wave bridge, and emptied by the circuit as it needs current.  The capacitor is always charged up to the peak voltage each peak.  That means it would be at about a steady 15.6 V if the circuit doesn't draw any current.  If the circuit does draw current, then the voltage will drop some between peaks, then get refilled to the 15.6 V level each peak.  Since there are 2 peaks per line cycle, the capacitor is charged up to the full 15.6 V level twice per line cycle, or every 10 ms for 50 Hz input.

We can calculate how much the voltage dips between peaks.  For simplicity, let's say the cap gets charged to 15.6 V instantaneously every 10 ms, and that the circuit draws 700 mA continuously.  The voltage drop on a capacitor, in common units, is:

V = A s / F

Plugging in our numbers, we get:

(700 mA)(10 ms)/(1 mF) = 7 V

The voltage on the capacitor will therefore roughly be a sawtooth with peaks of 15.6 V and low points of 8.6 V.  That's actually quite a lot of ripple.

The remaining part in your schematic is a 7805 regulator.  It makes a steady 5 V out, as long as the input voltage stays high enough for the 7805 to operate.  That's about 7.5 V for most 7805 variants.  Since the minimum input voltage to the 7805 is 8.6 V in this case, the required conditions have been met.

However, you have to consider power dissipation.  One way to think of the 7805 is a variable resistor between the input and the output, plus some control circuitry.  The control circuit constantly tweaks the resistance so that it drops the right amount to keep the output at 5 V.  The input current of the 7805 is therefore the same as the output current.  Actually, the control circuit uses a little extra input current, but this is so small that you can ignore it in most cases.

The problem with this is that this conceptual tweaked resistor dissipates significant power.  Power is voltage times current.  You have 8.6 to 15.6 V at 700 mA going in, and 5 V at 700 mA going out.  Obviously the power going in is higher than the power going out.  You can also see this directly by looking at the voltage across the regulator, which is 3.6 to 10.6 V.  That times the 700 mA current comes out to significant power.  For a ideal sawtooth wave, this average power would be about 5 W.  That power will be turned into heat in the regulator.

5 W is a lot more heat than something in a TO-220 case can dissipate in free air without getting too hot.  It can handle that with a proper heat sink, but you definitely need a heat sink.  Without one, the 7805 will get hot fast.  That will cause it to shut down to prevent destroying itself.  After it cools for a little while, it will turn on again, then get too hot again, etc.  The output will keep going on and off, not allowing whatever you have connected to run properly.

Just to get started, you can make this work by putting a decent heat sink on the 7805 regulator.

A better answer is to replace the 7805 with a buck switcher.  Those are much more efficient.  For a linear regulator like the 7805, the input *current* is the output *current*, plus a little for losses.  For a switcher, the input *power* is the output *power*, plus a little for losses.  Let's say you use a switcher that is 90% efficient.  That's good but achievable.  The output power is (700 mA)(5 V) = 3.5 W.  The input power to the switcher would therefore be (3.5 W)/90% = 3.9 W.  The 400 mW difference will heat the switcher.  In many cases, that's low enough to not require deliberate heat sinking.

Comment: That is really a great explanation.. thanks a lot..

Answer (score 2):

12Vdc down to 5V with a linear reg is 4.9W dissipation and way too much. Use a 6V transformer and an LDO or a switching regulator if using a 12V transformer. Look at the datasheet of the regulator(s) for appropriate input and output capacitors.

The available current is down to the transformer you choose and then the regulator you select.

For example, a 1A regulator will give you up to 1A assuming you do not dissipate too much power and therefore overheat it. You need to do a bit of research about power dissipation, how it induces a temperature rise and how heatsinking can help limit this rise. As P = VI, if you have 12V in, 5V out you are dropping 7V across the 7805 as it is. With 0.7A through it, that's 4.9W. Just look at the datasheet to work out how much that would heat up the device!

For the transformer, it's a case of ensuring you select a device with a secondary winding capable of delivering enough current. Also, remember that a 12V transformer will give you 12 * root 2 (about 1.41) Volts dc, before the voltage dropped across the bridge rectifier (roughly 1.4V); more than 12V once smoothed. (12 * 1.41) - 1.4 = around 15.5V.

Switching regulators help a lot with switching from something like 12V to 5V as you are not just losing all that power in the regulator itself, but that's a whole separate issue that needs study.

Comment: To explain: 12 V input for the 7805, 5 V out, that's 12 - 5 = 7 V drop. At a current of 0.7 A means the power that the  7805 has to "burn" is 7V * 0.7 A = 4.9 Watt. You'd need a heatsink of around 10x10x2 cm for that. I would suggest using an LM2596 based DCDC converter board, these are cheap (cheaper than a heatsink !) and no heatsink is needed.

Comment: Is that not what I said? (Sorry if that sounds sarcastic - not meant to be!)

Comment: Yes it is what you said, just wanted to explain that the **current** is involved and how you get to the 4.9 W. OP is a beginner you see, might not know the current is involved or how you got the 4.9 W.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie is it something like that?
https://goo.gl/Dr2RyW

Comment: @sforsandeep Yes that's the DCDC module I mean. They're cheap and very handy, just adjust the pot (blue) to get 5 V out and you're done. I use them all the time.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Thanks a lot for that info.. Is that OK for running 24x7

Comment: Yes you can run it continously, no problem. 0.7 A is not a huge current for such a converter so it will not be stressed very much.

Comment: @sforsandeep beware of these "LM2596" modules. Nowadays most of them are produced with fake ICs, which work on lower frequencies (about 50kHz instead of 150kHz) and have very poor behaviour.I would go for something based on MP2307 or MP1584.

Comment: @todor simeonov By lower frequency you mean there is serious chance of noise,isn't it. I just had a search for that ic based modules and it find 4 times expensive than lm2596. That's the only concern if it's a less cost project we are planning is...

Comment: @bimpelrekkie out of curiosity on those boards, if we set the output voltage to 5v but if input varies like +/- 1v does it affect the output?? I mean will it stay 5v sharp or that will also varie?

Comment: @sforsandeep As long as the input voltage is at least 2 V higher than the input voltage (so more than 7 V in your case) then you do not need to worry about this. The output will stay very close to 5 V for input voltages between 7  V and 37 V (maximum of LM2596). According to the datasheet the accuracy of the output voltage is 4 % which is **more than enough**. Your Arduino does not need 5.0000 V precisely, it can work with 2.7 to 5.5 V, it is not that picky ! So do not worry about the 5 V being accurate and stable enough, it will be if you use this module.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Waw.. thats some bonus info.. thanks for that..

Comment: @sforsandeep Lower frequency doesn't necessarily mean higher noise. It strongly depends on design. **I mean that there is very high chance to buy a 2596 module with fake IC**, which parameters do not  match the datasheet. And if something basic as the control frequency doesn't match, how can you be sure about all other stuff - voltage reference temperature stability, short circuit protection, over temperature protection and so on... Don't get me wrong - LM2596 is a good chip if original ;)

Comment: @TodorSimeonov Thanks a lot for those information. That was really clarified lots of questions I had in my mind.